# getting java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect while generating certificate

Tags: security, fips, java-security

I am trying to generate certificate using my java application.
I am getting bellow exception..

```
[main]ERROR pki.CertificateManager[<init>: 109][]: Failed to create keystore
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:215)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
```